# Как исправить проблему с node js

Tags: node.js

Всем привет. У меня windows 11.Я поставил себе node js для работы npm, yarn, js. И появилась такая проблема что node js перестает работать. При запуске команд npm или yarn

[image]

Появляется вот эта консоль. Она сама открывается при любой попытке работы node js.
Я попробовал в ручную удалить все что касается ноды и переустановил его. Работает какое-то время и опять появляется эта проблема. Попробовал удалить и установить с помощью nvm(node version manager) все равно та же проблема. Подскажите пожалуйста как решить эту проблему. Спасибо!

Comment: `При запуске команд npm...` а какой командой вы запускаете npm?

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/1901

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=node+automatically+pops+up+a+new+gnode.exe+window

Comment: при запуске любых команд npm install , yarn install и т.д. После многочисленных переустановок и чистки компа от ноды пока это проблема перестала беспокоить. Но думаю не я один сталкивался с такой проблемой и хорошо бы найти решение!